# How can I do Active list element function in my menubar?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The **active** list element is :

```html
<li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link nav__link--active " href="#"...
```

The normal list element is:

```html
<li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link " href="#"...
```

I want the element be active on select and normal when not selected.

Following is the code:

```
<div class="nav-section">
  <div class="nav-section__header">
    <h2 class="nav-section__title"> Heading </h2>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav">

    <li class="nav__item ">
      <a class="nav__link nav__link--active" href="../home/main1.php">
        <span class="channel-link__icon">
<span class="channel-link__element">Title1</span>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav__item ">
      <a class="nav__link nav__link--active" href="../home/main2.php">
        <span class="channel-link__icon"></span>
        <span class="channel-link__element">Title2</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: _"I want the element be active on select and normal when not selected."_ When you say "on select" do you mean when the element is focused or when the active route matches the particular nav link?

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla JavaScript, you have a `nav__link` elements as array, and we could reset the active flag on each element then add a `nav__link--active` to the caller.

For example:

#### HTML

```
<a class="nav__link nav__link--active" onclick="toggle(this)" href="../home/main2.php">
    <span class="channel-link__icon"></span>
    <span class="channel-link__element">Title2</span>
</a>
```

#### JavaScript

```
function toggle(element) {
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName("nav__link");
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].classList.remove("nav__link--active");
    }
    element.classList.add("nav__link--active");
}
```

Comment: @XNIPERDAD You have `main1.php`, `main2.php`, and a current file. It is likely your web browser reload the page after click on any link, and that clears the javascript changes. There is one way to do this, you remove the class for Title1 in `main1.php`, and remove class for Title2 in `main2.php`. You should be all set.